# how do i save a string outside of for loop in C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I am trying to write program that takes a string with symbols and numbers and only saves the alphabet, discarding everything else. I tried with a str.erase but I thought it was easier to use loop. Assuming everything is lower case,it works beautifully.copy_str should save the new string without the symbols, to see if it was done I displayed it. When it is inside the if-it shows correct string, but when I display it outside the for loop-nothing. :/
here is my code:

```
    int main()
{
 string str="am73$$ore r0ma!!!";


 int size_str=str.size();
 string copy_str;
 for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
    if((str[i]>=97) && (str[i]<123))
    {
        copy_str[i]=str[i];
        cout<<copy_str[i];
    }
 }
 cout<<copy_str;
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "it only saves the new string inside the if statement"? All your strings are declared outside of the `if` and `for` blocks, so they will retain the value even after these blocks have been executed.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `isalpha`, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/).

`copy_str` is uninitialized and you initialize only the positions where your if statement inside the loop is fulfilled. Add single chars using `+=`.

```
std::string src = "am73$$ore r0ma!!!";

std::string dst; // empty string

for ( size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( isalpha(src[i]) ){ dst += src[i]; }
}
std::cout << dst << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The program is undefined since you're assigning to non-existent elements of an empty string.
Assigning to an element that doesn't exist does not make the string longer, it's invalid.
Since the program is undefined, anything can happen.

You can use `push_back` to expand the result:

```
if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
{
    copy_str.push_back(str[i]);
}
```

or `+=`:

```
if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
{
    copy_str += str[i];
}
```

Comment: These are also "magic" numbers but chars instead of their decimal values... What about capitals?

Comment: @Gombat `'a'` and `'z'` are characters in the Latin alphabet, not magic numbers. This only handles lowercase because generalising it isn't part of the question.

Comment: 'str' is not empty  std::string str="am73$$ore r0ma!!!" the copy_str has to only contain the letters. I added symbols to check if code works.

Comment: @gps You're assigning to what would be the elements of `copy_str`, but `copy_str` is empty.